# Ajax data into textbox after function is called

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been looking at a few samples of ajax and realise that most of them will echo back the result. I have a few questions on jQuery/ajax

Is echo-ing the only it can return a data after the function processes it? Will it be possible for me to eg GRAB data from Textbox 1 2 3 and process it on process.php then pass the variable back via ajax and update the textbox's values?

Would be great if you have any samples on Grabbing data from textbox , pushing it to another php file and returning the variable to the actual form's textbox.

Thank you!

Comment: jquery.com has plenty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may start with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //May try POST too
    url: "somefile.php",
    data: $("#txtBox").val(),
    dataType: 'text', 
    success: function(data) {
        $("#txtBox").val(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert('Complete: Do something.');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error: Do something.');
    }
});​
```

> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: I understand, Thank you for helping me start learning. May i verify. Type"Get" Retieves data from somefile.php , data: $("#txtBox").val() Passes the data to somefile.php and i have to call it to retrieve it. How do i return the data to Success from somefile.php?

Comment: @RainbowHat you can simply output the data from somefile.php

Comment: So am i right to say i can ECHO from somefile.php ajax will catch it and pass it to $("#txtBox").val(data); ? What if i have two values, 2 textbox different data

Comment: yep whatever you echo out on your requested page will be teh returned data variable.  I recommend returning as json data though

Comment: the GET type refers to the type of http request in this case his code is doing a GET request which you access in php with $_GET or $_REQUEST in my example i use POST which is $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: Do you mean this echo json_encode($arr); i return a json array? then i call it using $("#txtBox").val(data[0]); first array

Comment: @RainbowHat just `echo` or `print` whatever you want to return. It could be plain text, json or even a PDF file. Just ensure that you use the proper return type, `text` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is using jquery, it reads in the contents of one select box posts the value of the selected item to a background php page which then returns a json array.
If the query was successful on the backend php page it makes a new div visible and outputs the returned html (in my case a 2nd drop down box) into the new div

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax/supplier-alert-lookup.php",
            data: {
                'supplier': $("select#usedsupplier").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                if (data["alertqueryresult"]==true) {
                    $("#alertoutputhtml").html(data["returnedalerthtml"]);
                    $("#supplieralertresult").css("display","");
                } else {
                    $("#supplieralertresult").css("display","none");
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```